# Add icon on every image in carousel

Tags: jquery, css

I've been having a hard time to get this done but no luck. I wanted to add icons on every image in a carousel. I used this carousel [here](https://github.com/specious/cloud9carousel). I loop all images but the icon is not on the right position. Anyone? Thanks!

```
 <div class="rotator" id="carousel-{{ trim($rotator) }}">
        {{-- */ $rotator_items=$rotators->where('rotator_id',$rotator)->all() /*  --}}

        @foreach ( $rotator_items as $items)
              {{-- items --}}
              <img id="{{ trim($items->id) }}" @if($items->item_name == 'default_item') onclick=" handleRotatorItem('{{ trim($items->id) }}'); "@else ondblclick="editRotatorItem({{ trim($items->item_id) }});" @endif alt="{{ trim($items->item_name) }}" class="img-rotator-item" src="{{ trim($items->img_src) }}" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ $items->notes }}">
                                    {{-- /assets/img/placeholder.png --}}
         </img>
         <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

Script:

```
 $(element).ImageRotator( {
            buttonLeft   : $("#ctrlRotatorItems > .left "),
            buttonRight  : $("#ctrlRotatorItems > .right "),
            autoPlay     : 1,
            bringToFront : true,
            farScale     : 0.2,
            yOrigin      : 100,
            yRadius      : 100,
            xRadius      : $('#main-content').width() / 2,
            speed        : 2,
            autoPlayDelay: 10000,
            onLoaded     : function(carousel) {
                var item = carousel.nearestItem();
                console.log(item);
            },
            onRendered   : function(carousel) {
                var item = carousel.nearestItem();

                $('#itemName').html(item.element.alt);
            },
            onAnimationFinished : function(carousel) {
                console.log(carousel);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is your code ? [code link](https://github.com/specious/cloud9carousel)

Comment: Yeah, This is just how I looped the images

Comment: But where you need the images ? anywhere of every carousel Images ?

Comment: @MDAshik, every images in carousel should have an icon for info.

Comment: So where is the `right position`

Comment: @FuXu right and where your Css and jQuery code ? here only I can see jason !

Comment: @FuXu, already added the script.

Comment: I mean where do you want to place your `info-circle` icon? For example `at the right bottom corner` of your image ?

Comment: @FuXu, at the right top corner of the image.